# How can I add shared library in anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, boost-python, anaconda3

When I use `python` command, I can import library (boost.python) from code if `.so` files are stored in the same folder as `.py` script. How I can do this with anaconda and Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: It's pretty much the same as in the command promt. Try `import sys` and `sys.path` in both Jupyter and CMD and see if you are in the same directory.

Comment: My previous comment shows you your python installation, your current working directory can be see with `imort os` and `print (os.getcwd()`

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda has a shell interface called “Anaconda Prompt”

inside the prompt, just use the following command:

```
conda install <yourPackageName>
```

and it will be available for your jupyter notebook

https://francescolelli.info/python/install-anaconda-and-import-libraries-into-the-ide/

Comment: This package does not exist in conda repositories. I coded it with boost.python C++ library.